# grako ebnf tags at new line; ingoring spaces

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, ebnf, grako

Trying to make a parser with grako to parse 
something like

```
tag1: line1
line 2 ... 
tag2: line1 
line2
...
```

such that whitespaces before tag1 should be ignored; but tags should start at new line.

**Small ebnf (x.ebnf)**

```
START = DATA $;

DATA = piece:{PIECE}+ ;

PIECE = x | y;

sep = ":";

xtag = /^\s*x[^:]*/ sep;
ytag = /^\s*y[^:]*/ sep;

x = xtag val:userinput ;
y = ytag val:userinput ;

userfirstinput = /.*/;
userinput = firstline+:userfirstinput lines:{line}*;
line  = !PIECE /.*/;
```

**input (test):**

```
  x: First
y: liney
liney2 x: is not x
```

**start:**

```
python3 xparser.py -t test START
```

**Error:**

```
grako.exceptions.FailedParse: test.event(1:1) no available options :
  x: First

^
PIECE
DATA
START
```

**Question:**
Why?!
I put ^\s*x , why it does not match?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: I think i also tried to use capitalized Xtag and Ytag, but then x: is not x is parsed as x expression, but not as another line of userinput

Comment: Ok, it seems that to get more or less what I want, I just need to use that:
`xtag = /x[^:]*/ sep;`
`ytag = /y[^:]*/ sep;`

Still, don't understand the difference between capitalized and non-capitalized things. Also in that solution, the information about whitespaces at the beginning of the line (in line) are lost...

Comment: How are you compiling the grammar? You need to specify "\t " as the whitespace characters, and use ``eol = /\r?\n|\r/;`` within your grammar, as in ``line = !PIECE /.*/ eol; ``.  Also, consuming input in an unstructured way with ``/.*`` is not good, as the first occurrence of it will match all the rest of the input sequence.

Comment: i compiled the grammar by running grako on it:
`grako x.ebnf > xparser.py &&
 python3 xparser.py -t test START`

Comment: You can set the whitespace characters with the ``-w`` option. For example, ``grako -w "\t " xparser.py``.  Then, you can use ``'\n'`` as a token in your grammar, for example: ``line  = !PIECE /.*$/;``. All in all, I think that your simple language could be better handled using only regular expressions.

Comment: It's a fragment of a grammar. But I think you pointed me out to the thing that I was missing: I have to treat newlines separately from other whitespaces. I'll try that. Thanks!